# After update chrome browser responsive blocks does not work anymore in my code

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsiveness

I have code form a developer for websites, responsiveness still works in Firefox, but in Chrome it does not work anymore after update browser version. I think since 112 version, but i am not sure. Is there any change of using code with this version related to my issue?

Site: https://matahome.nl

code:

file: resonsive_all.less

```
@responsivespacing-x: @ds;
@responsivespacing-y: @ds;
@breakpoint-item: 200px;
@breakpoint-fullwidth: 640px;
@breakpoint-to-1: @breakpoint-item*2;
@breakpoint-to-2: @breakpoint-item*3;
@breakpoint-to-3: @breakpoint-item*4;
@breakpoint-to-4: @breakpoint-item*5;
@breakpoint-to-5: @breakpoint-item*6;
@breakpoint-to-6: @breakpoint-item*7;
@breakpoint-to-7: @breakpoint-item*7;
@breakpoint-to-8: @breakpoint-item*8;
@breakpoint-to-9: @breakpoint-item*9;
@breakpoint-to-10: @breakpoint-item*10;
@breakpoint-to-11: @breakpoint-item*11;
@breakpoint-to-12: @breakpoint-item*12;
@breakpoint-to-13: @breakpoint-item*13;
@breakpoint-to-14: @breakpoint-item*14;



//The basics, also applies to no-js users.

.respfluid
{
    .ri
    {
        margin-bottom: @responsivespacing-y;
        float: left;
        + .ri
    {
            margin-left: @responsivespacing-x;
        }
        a.image
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
    //rc = Responsive Container, ri = Responsive Item
}
        
//Making it break using element queries generated by javascript [min-width~=xxxxx]
//                using breakpoint vars in them @{breakpoint-to-xx}

    //The actual breakpoints.
    //@todo: correct the breakpoint widths, they are not all ok!
.responsive
{
    //When looking for trouble in nested rc ri stacks, remove the below / rework the hell out of it.
    .ri .ri
    {
        .pr1;                   //ugly
        clear: none; //ugly
    }
    
     .s-ultimate
    {
        .ri .ri
        {
            .pr1;
            float: left; //ugly
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-13})
        {
            .pr14;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-12} <= @{breakpoint-to-13})
        {
            .pr13;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-11} <= @{breakpoint-to-12})
        {
            .pr12;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-10} <= @{breakpoint-to-11})
        {
            .pr11;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-9} <= @{breakpoint-to-10})
        {
            .pr10;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-8} <= @{breakpoint-to-9})
        {
            .pr9;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-7} <= @{breakpoint-to-8})
        {
            .pr8;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-6} <= @{breakpoint-to-7})
        {
            .pr7;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-5} <= @{breakpoint-to-6})
        {
            .pr6;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-4} <= @{breakpoint-to-5})
        {
            .pr5;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-3} <= @{breakpoint-to-4})
        {
            .pr4;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-2} <= @{breakpoint-to-3})
        {
            .pr3;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-1} <= @{breakpoint-to-2})
        {
            .pr2;
        }
        .ri:container(width <= @{breakpoint-to-1})
        {
            .pr1;
        }
    }
    
    .s7654321
    {
        .ri .ri
        {
            .pr1;
            float: left; //ugly
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-6})
        {
            .pr7;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-5} <= @{breakpoint-to-6})
        {
            .pr6;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-4} <= @{breakpoint-to-5})
        {
            .pr5;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-3} <= @{breakpoint-to-4})
        {
            .pr4;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-2} <= @{breakpoint-to-3})
        {
            .pr3;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-1} <= @{breakpoint-to-2})
        {
            .pr2;
        }
        .ri:container(width <= @{breakpoint-to-1})
        {
            .pr1;
        }
    }
    
    .s6421
    {
        .ri .ri
        {
            float: left; //ugly
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-6})
        {
            .pr6;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-3} <= @{breakpoint-to-6})
        {
            .pr4;
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-1} <= @{breakpoint-to-3})
        {
            .pr2;
        }
        .ri:container(width <= @{breakpoint-to-1})
        {
            .pr1;
        }
    }
    .s63
    {
        .ri .ri
        {
            float: left; //ugly
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-3})
        {
            .pr6;
        }
        .ri:container(width <= @{breakpoint-to-3})
        {
            .pr3;
        }
    }
    .s42
    {
        .ri .ri
        {
            float: left; //ugly
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-2})
        {
            .pr4;
        }
        .ri:container(width <= @{breakpoint-to-2})
        {
            .pr2;
        }
    }
    .s31
    {
        .ri .ri
        {
            float: left; //ugly
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-2})
        {
            .pr3;
        }
        .ri:container(width <= @{breakpoint-to-2})
        {
            .pr1;
            + &
            {
                .pr1;
            }
        }
    }
    .s21
    {
        .ri .ri
        {
            float: left; //ugly
        }
        .ri:container(width > @{breakpoint-to-1})
        {
            .pr2;
        }
        .ri:container(width <= @{breakpoint-to-1})
        {
            .pr1;
        }
    }
}

.clear-ri// Pasted css attributes using class selectors; to be able to use 'seven-a-row(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)' classes on other places as well.
{
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
}

//Extra, not for generic use

//Extra, not for generic use
.pr14(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(7.1428571% - " @margin / 14 * 13 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(14n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

.pr13(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(7.6923077% - " @margin / 13 * 12 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(13n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

//Extra, not for generic use
.pr12(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(8.3333333333333% - " @margin / 12 * 11 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(12n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

//Extra, not for generic use
.pr11(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(9.09090909090% - " @margin / 11 * 10 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(11n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

//Extra, not for generic use
.pr10(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(10% - " @margin / 10 * 9 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(10n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

.pr9(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(11.11111111% - " @margin / 9 * 8 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(9n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

.pr8(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(12.5% - " @margin / 8 * 7 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(8n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

.pr7(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(14.28% - " @margin / 7 * 6 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(7n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}


//whatever a row.... do it yourself from 7 on.
.seven-a-row(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    .rc .ri,
    &.rc .ri
    {
        .pr7(@margin);
    }
}

.pr6(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(16.6666667% - " @margin / 6 * 5 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(6n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}
.six-a-row(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    .rc .ri,
    &.rc .ri
    {
        .pr6(@margin);
    }
}

.pr5(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(20% - " @margin / 5 * 4 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(5n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

.five-a-row(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    .rc .ri,
    &.rc .ri
    {
        .pr5(@margin);
    }
}

.pr4(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(25% - " @margin / 4 * 3 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(4n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

.four-a-row(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    .rc .ri,
    &.rc .ri
    {
        .pr4(@margin);
    }
}

.pr3(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(33.333333% - " @margin / 3 * 4 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(3n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

.three-a-row(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    .rc .ri,
    &.rc .ri
    {
        .pr3(@margin);
    }
}

.pr2(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    width: ~"calc(50% - " @margin * 3 ~")";
    &:nth-of-type(2n+1)
    {
        .clear-ri;
    }
}

.two-a-row(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    .rc .ri,
    &.rc .ri
    {
        .pr2(@margin);
    }
}

.pr1(@margin: @responsivespacing-x) /*ignored*/
{
    .clear-ri;
    width: auto; 
    float: none;
}

.one-a-row(@margin: @responsivespacing-x)
{
    .rc .ri,
    &.rc .ri,
    .rc .ri + .ri,
    &.rc .ri + .ri
    {
        .pr1(@margin);
    }
}






In firefox it works fine:

[chrome versus firefox display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdTdR.jpg)

Also in firefox i can inspect the code (this is no longer available in chrome:
[inspector firefox display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFMZI.jpg)


Also there is also a cms.yml file:

search_limit: 100
inline-editable: 1
title_delimiter: '||'
backgroundslides: 1
backgroundslides_automaxwidth: 0
bannerslide: fade
delete_old_blocks_automatically: 0
delete_old_templates_automatically: 0
# or scroll
page_icons: 1
position_classes:
    respfluid s-ultimate: POSITION_CLASS_SULTIMATE
    respfluid s7654321: POSITION_CLASS_S7654321
    respfluid s6421: cms.POSITION_CLASS_S6421
    respfluid s63: cms.POSITION_CLASS_S63
    respfluid s42: cms.POSITION_CLASS_S42
    respfluid s31: cms.POSITION_CLASS_S31
    respfluid s21: cms.POSITION_CLASS_S21
    respfluid seven-a-row: cms.POSITION_CLASS_7R
    respfluid six-a-row: cms.POSITION_CLASS_6R
    respfluid four-a-row: cms.POSITION_CLASS_4R
    respfluid three-a-row: cms.POSITION_CLASS_3R
    respfluid two-a-row: cms.POSITION_CLASS_2R
    respfluid sbs: cms.POSITION_CLASS_FLUID
#analytics: UA-XXXX
responsive_auto_image: 1
redirectmembersonlyhidden: 1
secure_videos: 1
socialicon:
    width: ''
    params: 'y=32'
    add_dims: 0
langswitcher:
    image: x=33|y=23|crop
background:
    image: x=1680|y=1050
banner:
    image: x=1180|y=1180
    fill: 0
item:
    image: x=300|y=200
    image_large: x=1024|y=768
listitem:
    image: x=150|y=150
    imgwdth: 150
photogallery:
    image: x=154|y=115
categorylist:
    image: x=154|y=154
    imgwdth: 154
categorylist_wrapper:
    image: x=154|y=154
    limit: 9
iconimage:
    small: x=32|y=32
    photo: x=48|y=32|crop
pageiconimage: x=30|y=30|crop
personel:
    photo_overview: y=180|x=180|crop
    person_photo: x=90|y=90|crop
```